# how to declare enum lifetime with impl function?

Tags: rust

I'd like to declare an enum with an accessor function that returns the values that were provided when the value is created.  Below is a contrived example that illustrates the error:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SomeBytes<'a> {
  One([u8; 1]),
  Two([u8; 2]),
}

impl SomeBytes<'a> {

  pub fn get_bytes(&'a self) -> &'a[u8] {
    use SomeBytes::*;

    match *self {
      One(byte_array) => &byte_array,
      Two(byte_array) => &byte_array,
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let var1 = SomeBytes::One(*b"A");
  let var2 = SomeBytes::Two(*b"AB");

  println!("one byte = {:?}", var1);
  println!("sizeof one byte = {:?}", mem::size_of_val(&var1));
  println!("two bytes = {:?}", var2);
  println!("sizeof two bytes = {:?}", mem::size_of_val(&var2));
}
```

errors:

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
 --> src/main.rs:9:16
  |
9 | impl SomeBytes<'a> {
  |                ^^ undeclared lifetime

error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
  --> src/main.rs:11:21
   |
11 |   pub fn get_bytes(&'a self) -> &'a[u8] {
   |                     ^^ undeclared lifetime

error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
  --> src/main.rs:11:34
   |
11 |   pub fn get_bytes(&'a self) -> &'a[u8] {
   |                                  ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

How do I write this code so that it will compile?

See [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b15cd6b8cb7f93130fcec1aa5cd8b202)

If I remove all the lifetimes from my code (which current comments/answers say are not needed, then the example looks like this:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SomeBytes {
  One([u8; 1]),
  Two([u8; 2]),
}

impl SomeBytes {

  pub fn get_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
    use SomeBytes::*;

    match *self {
      One(byte_array) => &byte_array,
      Two(byte_array) => &byte_array,
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let var1 = SomeBytes::One(*b"A");
  let var2 = SomeBytes::Two(*b"AB");

  println!("one byte = {:?}", var1);
  println!("sizeof one byte = {:?}", mem::size_of_val(&var1));
  println!("two bytes = {:?}", var2);
  println!("sizeof two bytes = {:?}", mem::size_of_val(&var2));
}
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `byte_array`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     match *self {
15 | |       One(byte_array) => &byte_array,
16 | |       Two(byte_array) => &byte_array,
   | |                          ----------- `byte_array` is borrowed here
17 | |     }
   | |_____^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `byte_array`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     match *self {
15 | |       One(byte_array) => &byte_array,
   | |                          ----------- `byte_array` is borrowed here
16 | |       Two(byte_array) => &byte_array,
17 | |     }
   | |_____^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I must have added lifetimes in an attempt to fix the above error, but that wasn't the solution.  I was attempting to tell the compiler that I don't want to return something owned by the current function...  Can someone explain the appropriate fix?

Comment: KISS: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e6f7a8172fe52b9503d495cf06b9f45

Comment: Note: to declare a generic over impl just do `impl<'a>` but this wouldn't have help you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stargateur gave you the code without the explanation; let's see if I can fill in the gaps.

The reason your code does not work is that declaring a lifetime on a `struct` associates this lifetime **with the struct**. In other words, every method using or returning `'a` in your case will take or return the same `'a` irrespective of where and how this was placed. This is worthwhile when you have a reference inside a `struct`, which you do not. As a result, this is not necessary.

If you had wanted to go the whole hog and specify lifetimes, you could have done it like so:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum SomeBytes {
  One([u8; 1]),
  Two([u8; 2]),
}

impl SomeBytes {

  pub fn get_bytes<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a [u8] {
    use SomeBytes::*;

    match self {
      One(ref byte_array) => byte_array,
      Two(ref byte_array) => byte_array,
    }
  }
}
```

The lifetime is defined as a property of the *method*, not the `struct`. Its additional requirement is obvious - `&self` needs to be guaranteed for the lifetime `'a` that its return parameter will also obey.

However, this is pedantry; in practice, this lifetime requirement is not mandatory and can be dropped in favour of the simpler, more automatic version:

```
  pub fn get_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
    use SomeBytes::*;

    match self {
      One(ref byte_array) => byte_array,
      Two(ref byte_array) => byte_array,
    }
  }
```

Note: To make the example work, `&` also needed to be removed before `byte_array` on right side of the match. Since your method takes `&self` the content of your pattern matches will be references themselves even if you match self (since you do not have ownership of the object), and as a result, the `&` would lead to a reference-of-a-reference

Comment: I've edited my question... in addition to removing lifetimes, it looks like you removed a `&` from `One(byte_array) => &byte_array,` ... that seems to be the main problem.    I guess maybe `ref` returns a reference, and then `&byte_array` was a locally scoped reference to the struct field reference ?

Comment: @Ultrasaurus Correct! Since your method takes `&self` the content of your pattern matches will be references themselves even if you `match self` (since you do not have ownership of the object), and as a result, the `&` would lead to a reference-of-a-reference